# About a matlab mathematic problem from applied numerical method

Tags: functions, matlab

[image]

[image]

Can you help me,please to solve this problem with the help of Matlab.
Thanks!

Comment: The function 'fminsearch' will solve this (negated) problem. See the examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an analytical solution simply run 
[max( 0.4 / sqrt(1+x^2) - sqrt(1+x^2) * (1 - 0.4 / (1+x^2)) + x)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max%28%200.4%20/%20sqrt%281%2bx%5E2%29%20-%20sqrt%281%2bx%5E2%29%20%2a%20%281%20-%200.4%20/%20%281%2bx%5E2%29%29%20%2b%20x%29) on Wolfram Alpha (or a similar expression in any symbolical language, even Matlab provides a symbolic toolbox). An analytical solution should always be preferred, if applicable.

But I suppose you are interested in a purely numerical approach?

So, let us at first define the function (inline):

```
f = @(x) 0.4 / sqrt(1+x^2) - sqrt(1+x^2) * (1 - 0.4 / (1+x^2)) + x;
```

Plot it (play with the range) to get an impression on it:

```
fplot(f, [0 2])
```

The function seems to have a global optimum somewhere near to 1. So now negate it

```
fneg = @(x) -f(x)
```

to make it compatible with the built-in numerical *minimization* functions. Now just minimize fneg. For example by:

```
fminsearch(fneg, 1)
```

where 1 is passed as starting position for the local search. Take a look at

```
doc fminsearch
```

Alternatively use

```
fminbnd(fneg, 0, 2)
```

in order to search for a minimum in the interval [0,2]. The result is x=1.0519, which also matches the result at Wolfram Alpha.